# How can I read coordinates from a graph in Java?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, graph, coordinates

My aim is to read coordinate point values from a graph in a Java program. I don't know if it even needs to be a graph. The user clicks on various parts of a plane, and I need to know which places were clicked pixel-wise so that I can find the distances between those points. Are there any simple Java libraries for accomplishing this task?

Answer (score 4):

Just add a mouse listener to a JPanel.

In the mouse listener, you can do something like the following:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
       System.out.println("Mouse clicked at (" + e.getX() +"," +
                    + e.getY + ")");
    }
```

Comment: Plus, the Point class has a method to get the distance between two points named, appropriately enough, `Point.distance`. It comes in both the static and instance method flavors.